# FragmentManager Showing Error in android studio.what i did wrong here?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {

        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB f2=manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changetext(data);


    }
}
```

Comment: please post the error to

Comment: post error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `Activity` extends `AppCompatActivity`, which in turn extends `FragmentActivity`, you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html).

Comment: I am just learning.I know my question is quite lame and I am sorry about that.
And thanks for your answer. It is about AppCompatActivity and Activity.
Now i am using the getSupportFragmentManager() it works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your code, not `getFragmentManager()` - see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) for more details.

OR

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()`, or change the `import` for `FragmentManager` from what you have (`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`) to `android.app.FragmentManager`.

Comment: just by changing import your issue can be solved. you can do that both the way

Comment: you 2nd option did not work. I think it has something to do with Activity and AppCompatActivity. Any way thanks for the help